# Plotting a corrugated ribbon on a 3D Plot

Tags: calculus, vectors

We are produced the following code

```
Clear[P, t]; 
P[t_] = {-t, t, (1/2) t (8 - t)}; 
arch = ParametricPlot3D[P[t], {t, 0, 8}, Axes -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, PlotRange -> 
All, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> CMView, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

The output from the code is the following:

[image]

We were then tasked with obtaining the unit tangent vectors, the unit normal and binormal vectors through the following code:

```
Clear[P, x, y, z, t, unittan, mainunitnormal, binormal]; 
P[t_] = {-t, t, (1/2) t (8 - t)};
curve = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[P[t]], {t, 0, 8}]; 
unittan[t_] = P'[t]/Sqrt[P'[t] . P'[t]]; 
unittanvectors = Table[Vector[unittan[t], Tail -> P[t]], {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
mainunitnormal[t_] = N[unittan'[t]/Sqrt[Expand[unittan'[t] . unittan'[t]]]]; 
mainnormalvectors = Table[Vector[mainunitnormal[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red], {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
binormal[t_] = N[Cross[unittan[t], mainunitnormal[t]]]; 
binormalvectors = Table[Vector[binormal[t], Tail -> P[t], VectorColor -> Red], {t, 0, 8, 0.5}]; 
everything = Show[curve, unittanvectors, mainnormalvectors, binormalvectors, ViewPoint -> CMView, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

Which produces the following plot with vectors:

[image]

We are asked to plot a ribbon two units wide whose center curve coincides with the curve plotted above. Corrugate the ribbon if possible:

The hint that was provided was to use binormal[t]

One of the Plots I produced was using the following code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[P[t] + s mainunitnormal[t] +  Cos[3 s] binormal[t], {t, 0, 8}, {s, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> {15, 15}, ViewPoint -> CMView, BoxRatios -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Is my plot in line with what the question asks? And how can i go about to ensure that the ribbon is only two units wide?

Comment: Thanks, Will try it there.